# Wi-Fi connection turns off all the time

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have a Wi-Fi network in my appartment with the wireless N home router Trendnet tew-652BRP. Everything work fine for three of my laptops, but I have one PC with a D-Link DWA-140 adapter.
It loses connection 2-3 times in 5 minutes. There is the following messages in my system log when it does so:

1. The browser has forced an election on network \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{9537A5C1-3B43-4C56-B94C-CE69A257C3AD} because a master browser was stopped.
2. The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service was successfully sent a stop control.

   The reason specified was: 0x40030011 [Operating System: Network Connectivity (Planned)]

   Comment: None
3. The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service entered the stopped state.

in order of appearence.

How can I stop it? I have the latest driver installed.

Comment: I think NetBIOS and the computer browser service are too high a level to diagnose the problems you are having (ie the connection dropping)...

Comment: I think when I had some Intel driver running on Win it had its own error log... is there any D-Link specific log files you can find?

Comment: And can you just confirm that 'looses connection' means the adaptor is no longer connected to the WLAN?

Comment: When connection lost computer makes a sound, just like when I plug adaptor out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one PC loses the wireless connection, then it can be its adapter.
Try another adapter to verify whether this adapter is bad.

There is also the question of how far the PC is from the router. If it's the furthest in the apartment, or if there are solid walls between it and the router, this could explain the problem. In this case you would need to reposition the PC or router, or get a stronger router.

This can also be interference by your next-door neighbor's router.
Try to change the channel of the router to 11 (the strongest channel). Do so in any case.

Comment: changing channel helped! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your USB wireless adapter is just getting "pulled out". You mentioned it has a loose connection. I think there may be nothing wrong with network, just this USB network adapter.

If you have a very short USB extension cable you could try connecting it that way and then trying very hard to not "jostle" it the adapter. That is probably what causes the disconnection. (If this is indeed what is happening ...)